# Extract Jira issue id from Git Branch name using Windows Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, jira

I have a branch name in the form of:

```
origin/release/JIRA-1000-some-issue-name
```

I want to write a Batch script to extract only the Jira issue ID as such:

```
JIRA-1000
```

So that I could use the ID in a commit message further on.

Could someone please suggest a solution!

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=3,4 delims=/-" %%G IN ("origin/release/JIRA-1000-some-issue-name") do echo %%G-%%H`

Comment: @Squashman that worked! Thank you. 
How did %%H derive its value if it wasn't explicitly assigned?

Comment: Or perhaps, slightly safer: ```@For %%G In ("origin/release/JIRA-1000-some-issue-name") Do @For /F "Tokens=1,2" %%H In ("%%~nxG") Do @Echo %%H-%%I```. To find out what happens, open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: @Compo thanks for the suggestion. I have implemented a similar script. Shall update the question with the working answer.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my omission @Mofi. kartiks77, here it is in its entirety: ```@For %%G In ("origin/release/JIRA-1000-some-issue-name") Do @For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=-" %%H In ("%%~nxG") Do @Echo %%H-%%I```

Comment: @Compo. Got it. This is a very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Suggestions in the Comments, I was able to arrive at a solution.

The Batch Script has the following steps:

1. Retrieve Branch Name and store into temporary file
2. Set variable `branch_name`
3. Use Forward Slashes as delimiter and set parameter `lastPart`
4. Use `lastPart` to extract Jira ID with delimiters /-

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > %temp%\git.txt
for /f "Tokens=*" %%a in (%temp%\git.txt) do @set branch_name=%%a
for %%a in ("%branch_name%\.") do set "lastPart=%%~nxa"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/-" %%G in ("%lastPart%\.") do @set jiraid=%%G-%%H

echo %branch_name%
echo %lastPart%
echo %jiraid%
```

The output should be:

```
origin/release/JIRA-1000-some-issue-name
JIRA-1000-some-issue-name
JIRA-1000
```

Then the variable `jiraid` can be used further.